# Element-wise multiplication of multiple column with a specific column on a row by row basis

Tags: pandas, dataframe

- The table on the left is the original dataframe. The Table on the right is the desired dataframe.
- The values in column [0, 1, 2] are percentages and need to be
  multiplied by the column "Total Cost" for that particular row.
- By doing so, you get the desired answer table on the right.
- It seems like an element wise multiplication of df.row[0, 1, 2] *
  df.row[Total Cost]
- But not sure how to do this with pandas
- dict version of simplified dataframe provided below

[image]
    .

```
{0: {"Nov '18": 0.1666471015536077, "Dec '18": 0.5403863967743445, "Jan '19": 0.5362702245675458, "Feb '19": 0.3538342118892141, "Mar '19": 0.6068213241958712, "Apr '19": 0.6959594096743349, "May '19": 0.682575498865738}, 1: {"Nov '18": 0.2993902407933448, "Dec '18": 0.44429158402908286, "Jan '19": 0.3729695419273137, "Feb '19": 0.3980823560973494, "Mar '19": 0.3200835471705221, "Apr '19": 0.29763667231002056, "May '19": 0.2840070502525354}, 2: {"Nov '18": 0.5337308848310992, "Dec '18": 0.013817091931355035, "Jan '19": 0.07008689274226004, "Feb '19": 0.10680130054564026, "Mar '19": 0.06818860955654642, "Apr '19": 0.004524516700862339, "May '19": 0.004338865464848797}, 'xTrader (838)': {"Nov '18": 75319.0, "Dec '18": 42484.39, "Jan '19": 40484.71, "Feb '19": 40470.29, "Mar '19": 66609.0, "Apr '19": 71057.87999999999, "May '19": 89627.88}}



{0: {'Owner': 'system_voy', 'App': 'Voyager', 'LOB': 'Risk Management: Capital Markets', 'Transit': '83534', "Nov '18": 0.1666471015536077, "Dec '18": 0.5403863967743445, "Jan '19": 0.5362702245675458, "Feb '19": 0.3538342118892141, "Mar '19": 0.6068213241958712, "Apr '19": 0.6959594096743349, "May '19": 0.682575498865738, "Jun '19": 0.7032990347937492}, 1: {'Owner': 'eu\\xtradereod', 'App': 'xTrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: Global Markets', 'Transit': '75088', "Nov '18": 0.2993902407933448, "Dec '18": 0.44429158402908286, "Jan '19": 0.3729695419273137, "Feb '19": 0.3980823560973494, "Mar '19": 0.3200835471705221, "Apr '19": 0.29763667231002056, "May '19": 0.2840070502525354, "Jun '19": 0.2929727958768866}, 2: {'Owner': 'eu\\system_xtrader2', 'App': 'xTrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: Global Markets', 'Transit': '75088', "Nov '18": 0.5337308848310992, "Dec '18": 0.013817091931355035, "Jan '19": 0.07008689274226004, "Feb '19": 0.10680130054564026, "Mar '19": 0.06818860955654642, "Apr '19": 0.004524516700862339, "May '19": 0.004338865464848797, "Jun '19": 0.0027272448226331497}, 3: {'Owner': 'mr-tech', 'App': 'FRTB', 'LOB': 'Risk Management: Capital Markets', 'Transit': '83534', "Nov '18": 4.021308836676355e-06, "Dec '18": 7.853538029670704e-05, "Jan '19": 0.015370002324550705, "Feb '19": 0.11787934038028858, "Mar '19": 1.5161864573662851e-07, "Apr '19": 1.0092819280702894e-06, "May '19": 9.714219073341933e-06, "Jun '19": 1.1635748117981739e-07}, 4: {'Owner': 'eu\\system_xtsup_prd', 'App': 'xTrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: Global Markets', 'Transit': '75088', "Nov '18": 0, "Dec '18": 0, "Jan '19": 0, "Feb '19": 0.021433060967667138, "Mar '19": 0, "Apr '19": 0, "May '19": 0.016256659135696943, "Jun '19": 0}, 5: {'Owner': 'xt-tech', 'App': 'xTrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: Global Markets', 'Transit': '75088', "Nov '18": 0.00022774976090734464, "Dec '18": 2.212229303038311e-06, "Jan '19": 0.004022482749891066, "Feb '19": 0.00011334322251753845, "Mar '19": 0.0036268312234368394, "Apr '19": 4.7611888584087586e-05, "May '19": 0.0103897652257289, "Jun '19": 0.0010008081492497863}, 6: {'Owner': 'ad\\watb', 'App': 'CVATrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: RMG', 'Transit': '91707', "Nov '18": 0, "Dec '18": 0, "Jan '19": 0.0012585476083139418, "Feb '19": 0.0017582009987088963, "Mar '19": 0.001275486891583217, "Apr '19": 0.0015783820251811566, "May '19": 0.0006181777165474082, "Jun '19": 0}, 7: {'Owner': 'ad\\xustev', 'App': 'xTrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: Global Markets', 'Transit': '75088', "Nov '18": 0, "Dec '18": 0.0014241796556178747, "Jan '19": 2.2308080124760536e-05, "Feb '19": 9.818589861410218e-05, "Mar '19": 4.049343394433275e-06, "Apr '19": 0.00025239811908896236, "May '19": 0.0006735771849304808, "Jun '19": 0}, 8: {'Owner': 'ad\\cvatrader', 'App': 'CVATrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: RMG', 'Transit': '91707', "Nov '18": 0, "Dec '18": 0, "Jan '19": 0, "Feb '19": 0, "Mar '19": 0, "Apr '19": 0, "May '19": 0.0011116369831956367, "Jun '19": 0}, 9: {'Owner': 'ad\\mccloske', 'App': 'xTrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: Global Markets', 'Transit': '75088', "Nov '18": 0, "Dec '18": 0, "Jan '19": 0, "Feb '19": 0, "Mar '19": 0, "Apr '19": 0, "May '19": 1.905495170508051e-05, "Jun '19": 0}, 10: {'Owner': 'anonymous', 'App': 'xTrader', 'LOB': 'Capital Markets: Global Markets', 'Transit': '75088', "Nov '18": 1.752204286133488e-09, "Dec '18": 0, "Jan '19": 0.0, "Feb '19": 0, "Mar '19": 0, "Apr '19": 0, "May '19": 0, "Jun '19": 0}, 'xTrader (838)': {'Owner': 0.0, 'App': 0.0, 'LOB': 0.0, 'Transit': 0.0, "Nov '18": 75319.0, "Dec '18": 42484.39, "Jan '19": 40484.71, "Feb '19": 40470.29, "Mar '19": 66609.0, "Apr '19": 71057.87999999999, "May '19": 89627.88, "Jun '19": 0.0}}
```

Comment: provided dataframe-dict, would that help?

Comment: Sorry, thought I was making it easier to the reader. Let me upload without any modification. On sec

Comment: That works for the dataframe example, i provided in the example. Though with multiple columns i get the following exception: Operrands could not be broadcasted together with shapes (132,) (12,). Can I upload a modified dataframe with my raw input?

Comment: The second dataframe has multindex column, that get's lost when converted to dict. But would look like my image above. I can try to reverse-engineering to work for multindex using your example (Which works for the simplified version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need [`df.mul()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with [`df.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) :

```
data.iloc[:,:-1]=data.iloc[:,:-1].mul(data.iloc[:,-1],axis=0)
print(data)
```

---

```
                    0             1             2  xTrader (838)
Apr '19  49453.400218  21149.430945    321.502565       71057.88
Dec '18  22957.986431  18875.456930    587.010722       42484.39
Feb '19  14319.773167  16110.508395   4322.279605       40470.29
Jan '19  21710.744523  15099.563744   2837.447527       40484.71
Mar '19  40419.761583  21320.444993   4541.975094       66609.00
May '19  61177.794903  25454.949819    388.883313       89627.88
Nov '18  12551.693042  22549.773546  40200.076515       75319.00
```

**Note**: the sum of the provided data is `0.9981205987006647` , this is the reason why the sum of each row doesn't match the last. Else, this logic should work.

Comment: Transforming and setting the Index to ['Owner', 'App', 'LOB', 'Transit'] with ['data.iloc[:-1].mul(data.iloc[-1], axis=1)  got me the final answer for the second dataframe I provided. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to update the dataframe in-place is to operate on the underlying numpy ndarray directly.

```
df.values[:, :-1] *= df.values[:, [-1]]
```

If you want to create a new dataframe rather than updating in-place, you could do

```
df_new = df.iloc[:, :-1].mul(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0).join(df.iloc[:, -1])
```